# iOS - differences between results

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have this discrepancy between two values that have to be the same...

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0f)

... 
CGFloat angle = -3.0f;
CGFloat beta = degreesToRadian(90.0f - fabsf(angle));

CGFloat delta = (90.0f - fabsf(angle)) * M_PI /180.0f;
```

at this point I get beta = 282.72 and delta = 1.51 ?

Both values have to be the same!

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro is broken - change:

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0f)
```

to:

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0f)
```

**NB**: this is yet another example of why you should not use the preprocessor for this kind of thing. C and Objective C have had inline functions for 20 years now - you should make use of them.

Comment: can you explain why this kind of stuff happens?

Comment: Expressions will **not**, I repeat **not** be evaulated before they are inserted to a macro.  It is literally a copy and paste job.  So you will bork your order of operations.  You want `M_PI` * (90.0f - fabsf(angle)) / 180.f` but you are getting `M_PI` * 90.0f - fabsf(angle) / 180.f` . I hope I don't need to explain the difference between those two...

Comment: ok. thanks..... not everybody has the same level of knowledge of most advanced people. I know a lot of things but I am always learning and I always love to learn. I've asked because I always want to know the reason behind stuff, so I can improve.